# Tengo un problema con una condición múltiple

Tags: tkinter, condiciones, while

En un juego que diseño con tkinter, necesito un botón (boton_contador) cuyo texto reporta el valor de un contador regresivo. La primera vez que se presiona el botón debe aparecer un mensaje (Label) que también reporta el valor del contador y una caja de entrada (Entry) que debe recibir un texto. Cuando el texto de la caja esté listo se debe presionar otro botón (boton_final) para finalizar el proceso. Antes de hacer la pregunta les muestro un código que contiene los elementos comentados.

```
    # boton_y_mensaje.py

from tkinter import Tk, IntVar, StringVar, Button, Entry, Label

ventana = Tk()

contador = IntVar()
contador.set(5)

mensaje = StringVar()

def finaliza():
    quit()

def muestra_mensaje():
    Label(ventana, text="Mensaje alterno "+str(contador.get())).pack()
    alterno = Entry(ventana, width=10, textvariable=mensaje)
    alterno.pack()
    boton_final = Button(ventana, text="Fin", command=finaliza)
    boton_final.pack()

# while contador.get() > 0:
if True:
    contador.set(contador.get()-1)
    boton_contador = Button(ventana, text="Botón mensaje "+str(contador.get()), command=muestra_mensaje)
    boton_contador.pack()

ventana.mainloop()
```

Lo que en realidad necesito es que el usuario tenga cinco posibilidades de presionar el boton contador, lo que cambiaría el mensaje con cada presión. Después de la quinta presión solo le quedará como alternativa escribir el mensaje y luego salir, pero no tiene porqué usar las cinco posibilidades si no lo desea y antes de eso puede escribir el mensaje y presionar el botón de salida.

Me queda claro que debo escribir un while en alguna parte. Lo que no he podido conseguir es la manera de combinar las dos condiciones de salida.

---

Muchas gracias por tu pedagógica y detallada respuesta, Dante. Pero creo que hay algo que no expresé bien, quizás por no hacer la petición demasiado larga. La idea es que el widget que lleva el mensaje **Intentos 5** (4, 3, ...) sea el propio botón modificador del mensaje **Mensaje alterno 5** (4, 3, ...) que, por supuesto, irá en un Label.

En la dinámica que espero, el botón con el 5 aparecerá sin compañía en la ventana. Al presionarlo, aparecerán por primera vez el mensaje y el Entry. Presiones sucesivas del botón le bajarán el número y también cambiarán el mensaje, hasta que se presione el botón que señala el fin del contenido del Entry. Permítanme plantearlo de manera más gráfica.

En la ventana inicial solo iría el botón

**Intentos 5**

y luego de presionarlo

**Intentos 4**

Mensaje alterno 4

[(Entry)]     **Listo**

Las presiones posteriores del botón seguirían bajando los números hasta 0, poero debo poder interrumpir el proceso presionando el botón **Listo**.

Answer (score 0):

#### Problema de concepto: Uso de While

Usar un while para eso no tiene sentido en Tkinter. En este caso, el contador de intentos debe modificarse cuando se presione el botón. El mainloop de Tkinter se encargará de detectar cuando se presiona el botón y llamar a la función correspondiente.

#### Por que recrear los widgets al presionar un botón no es buena idea.

Por que los widgets anteriores no dejan de existir. Simplemente la interfaz se volverá un desastre apenas presiones el botón al tratar de ubicar los nuevos widgets. Si, es verdad que podrías eliminar los widgets anteriores, pero para que lo harías si puedes modificar los originales?

No te equivoques, puede ser hasta conveniente crear widgets cuando un botón se presiona, pero este no es el caso.

#### La mejor manera de cerrar el programa

Lo habitual es cerrar la ventana con `laventana.destroy()` en lugar de `quit`. Esto automáticamente finaliza el mainloop y, como se llega al final del programa, termina la ejecución.

#### Solución

En este caso usaré `import tkinter as tk` en lugar del `from tkinter import ...`. Es por una preferencia personal. Si la quieres usar, tendrás que colocar el prefijo `tk.` cada vez que necesites usar algo de Tkinter.

```
import tkinter as tk

# inicializo la ventana
ventana = tk.Tk()

def intento():
    intentos = contador.get()

    if(intentos > 0):
        nueva_cantidad_intentos = intentos - 1
        contador.set(nueva_cantidad_intentos)
        
        # El método config nos permite modificar un widget. Recibe los mismos argumentos que cuando haces por ejemplo Label(...).
        label_intentos.config(text="Intentos: " + str(nueva_cantidad_intentos))

def cerrar():
    # destruyo la ventana
    ventana.destroy()

# inicializo las variables. Le indicamos al contador que inicie en 5 usando el argumento value
contador = tk.IntVar(value=5)
message = tk.StringVar()

label_intentos = tk.Label(ventana, text=f"Intentos: " + str(contador.get()))
label_intentos.pack()

alterno = tk.Entry(ventana, width=10, textvariable=message)
alterno.pack()

boton_contador = tk.Button(ventana, text="Enviar", command=intento)
boton_contador.pack()

boton_final = tk.Button(ventana, text="Fin", command=cerrar)
boton_final.pack()

# Ahora, con todos los widgets creados, inicio el mainloop
ventana.mainloop()
```

Como podrás ver, primero creé todos los widgets y luego inicié el mainloop. No había necesidad de ningún while (ni convenía).
Espero que hayas aprendido algo con mi respuesta. Cualquier duda dime c:

Comment: La pregunta fue editada con un comentario refiriendo esta respuesta.